# onchange event fires alternatety

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, onchange

So I'm working on `hiding` and `showing` controls in php and I have this `<select>` field with `change event` and in `onchange` I want to hide the controls for '*Single Employee*' as well as for the other options.  So here is my code:

```
  <select name="civilstatus" class="form-control" id="civilstatus">
        <option value="Single">Single</option>
        <option value="Married">Married</option>
        <option value="Widow">Widow</option>
        <option value="Annulled">Annulled</option>
        <option value="Seperated">Seperated</option>
  </select>

  $(document).on('change','#civilstatus',function(){
    var cstatus = $(this).val();
    if(cstats === 'Single'){
        $('#spouse').slideUp( 1000 ).hide(0);
        $('.spouse').slideUp( 1000 ).hide(0);
        return false;
    }else{
        $('.spouse').val(null);
        $('#spouse').fadeToggle( 1000 ).show();
        $('.spouse').fadeToggle( 1000 ).show();
        return false;
    }
})
```

And so my problem is that when I select alternately it also works alternately. What I want is just to hide the controls only when the value of my `<select>` is **Single**. Because when I select other options `Widow` for example then the controls hide, when I select Seperated the controls are showing. So how to fix this?

Comment: It looks to me like you have a synchronicity issue.  The `slideUp` and  `fadeToggle` look like asynchronous processes that could enter a race condition.

Comment: @JeremyHolovacs so what to do now? Do I need to change the effects? or what?

Comment: Well first I'd decide to go with either id's or classes (classes seem to make more sense)... this seems to be using a shotgun approach that encourages race conditions.  Then I'd put any logic that should happen after the fades or slides occur in a callback to occur after the action is complete.  Look up how to use the jQuery callbacks.

Comment: Check the spelling cstatus and cstats.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that `fadeToggle().show()` is what you want? The `.show()` will not have any effect in this situation.

I think you are looking for `.fadeIn()`.

Answer (score 0):

I added a console log function to you can test you are getting the responses:
good luck :)

```
           <select name="civilstatus" class="form-control" id="civilstatus">
            <option value="Single">Single</option>
            <option value="Married">Married</option>
            <option value="Widow">Widow</option>
            <option value="Annulled">Annulled</option>
            <option value="Seperated">Seperated</option>
            </select>
            <script type="text/javascript">
            $('#civilstatus').on('change', function(){
            var cstatus = $(this).val();
            console.log(cstatus);
            if(cstatus == 'Single'){
                $('#spouse').slideUp( 1000 ).hide(0);
                $('.spouse').slideUp( 1000 ).hide(0);
                return false;
            }else{
                $('.spouse').val(null);
                $('#spouse').fadeToggle( 1000 ).show();
                $('.spouse').fadeToggle( 1000 ).show();
                return false;
            }
            });     

            </script>
```